# How to get $CHANGES from upstream Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

At the moment I trigger a downstream build the $CHANGES variable is empty (though I have changes, once build is completed changes are displayed.

I'm trying to pass this variable to the downstream job as one of the predefined parameters and no wonder it receives nothing.

How can I pass upstream changes to a downstream project?

Answer (score 1):

Display Upstream Changes is a Publisher, and needs to be enabled on a per-project basis in the Post-Build section of the job config. Once enabled, all subsequent builds will show the changes from upstream jobs on the build summary page (NOT the Recent Changes page!)
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Display+Upstream+Changes+Plugin

Comment: When I try the Display Upstream Changes plugin, it only shows the SCM changes of the last build. Any way to include more builds' SCM changes?